# is there a way to use c++0x at xcode? I want to use gcc 4.4 or greater

Tags: c++, iphone, xcode, c++11

I want to use gcc 4.4 or greater for iphone developement.
 anyone know how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you don't. Trust me you don't. Apple stays at gcc 4.2.1 because 4.2.2 and higher use the GPLv3 which means they'd have to give up control of their platform (a big problem for the iphone sdk). So they don't upgrade.

Unfortunately for you, you can't exactly just drop in a replacement gcc either, due to custom patches, ABI changes, etc.

Sorry.

Comment: Please clarify on how GPLv3 in GCC affects the iphone SDK.

Comment: Tivoization and patent provisions.

Comment: Which is exactly why Apple is pushing LLVM so hard.  If you want a newer compiler to look forward to, Clang / LLVM is clearly the future for Apple's platforms.

Comment: iOS development is Apple's walled garden, but you might as well install gcc_select and gcc v4.6 for normal development though.  C++0x's lambdas are kinda painful to live without.  Intel has a compiler for Mac OS X too.